# implementations of domino shuffling algorithm

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Are there many implementations of the "domino shuffling" algorithm as found in William Jockusch, James Propp amd Peter Shor's *Random Domino Tilings and the Arctic Circle Theorem* [math.CO/9801068](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801068)?  This topic may be out of fashion now but I wonder if any source code is circulating.  I'm doing it myself, but I always have this fear of "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 5):

I use http://halcanary.org/mathapplets/toadshuffle/toadshuffle-v1.3/ by Hal Canary.  (The reference Aaron Meyerowitz gave is for generating random tilings via coupling-from-the-past, which is quite different from domino-shuffling.)

Comment: what language is this written in?

Comment: I think if all I wanted to do is draw a nice picture, I may not even need CFTP, I would just start from uniform and swap.  For large tilings, that gets slow (if I remember).  Domino shuffling is very fast, but it only work in particular cirumstances... I still hve trouble implementing it... really should be on github or something.

Comment: The applet is written in Java (and, being a decade old, no longer works for all platform-and-browser configurations). 

Comment: I mean to translate that code into HTML5/canvas, but have not found the time yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one which produces ASCII art aztec diamond tilings.  It's written in perl.  As I recall, I wrote it as fast as possible, without making any attempt to do it efficiently, because I needed to make some pictures really quickly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

#=================================================================
sub delete_odd_blocks($) {
 my $diamond = shift; 
 for my $r (0..scalar @$diamond - 2) {
  my $c = index($$diamond[$r], "--" );
  while($c != -1) {
   if(substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 2) eq "==") {
    substr($$diamond[$r], $c, 2) = "BB";
    substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 2) = "BB";
   }
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "--", $c + 2);
  }
  $c = index($$diamond[$r], "!|" );
  while($c != -1) {
   if(substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 2) eq "!|") {
    substr($$diamond[$r], $c, 2) = "BB";
    substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 2) = "BB";
   }
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "!|", $c + 2);
        }
    }
}

#=================================================================
sub slide($) {
 my $diamond = shift;
 my $N = scalar @$diamond;  # $N rows in the diamond
 die "$N is an odd number" if($N % 2);
 my (@output);
 for my $r (0..$N/2) {
  my $row =  " "x$r . "A" x($N - 2*$r+2) . " "x$r;
  push @output, $row;
  unshift @output, $row;
 } 
 push @$diamond, " "x $N;
 for my $r (0..scalar @$diamond - 1) {
  my $c = index($$diamond[$r], "|" );
  while($c != -1) {
   if(substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 1) eq "|") {
    substr($output[$r+1],  $c, 1) = "|";
    substr($output[$r+2], $c, 1) = "|";
   }
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "|", $c + 1);
  }
  $c = index($$diamond[$r], "!" );
  while($c != -1) {
   if(substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 1) eq "!") {
    substr($output[$r+1],  $c+2, 1) = "!";
    substr($output[$r+2], $c+2, 1) = "!";
   }
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "!", $c + 1);
  }
  $c = index($$diamond[$r], "--" );
  while($c != -1) {
   substr($output[$r+2],  $c+1, 2) = "--";
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "--", $c + 2);
  }
  $c = index($$diamond[$r], "==" );
  while($c != -1) {
   substr($output[$r],  $c+1, 2) = "==";
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "==", $c + 2);
  }
 }
 pop @$diamond;
 \@output;
}
#=================================================================
sub fill_even_blocks($) {
    my $diamond = shift; 
 for my $r (0..scalar @$diamond - 2) {
  my $c = index($$diamond[$r], "AA" );
  while($c != -1) {
   if(substr($$diamond[$r+1], $c, 2) eq "AA") {
    if(rand() < 0.5) {
     substr($$diamond[$r],$c,2)  = "==";
     substr($$diamond[$r+1],$c,2)= "--";
    } else {
     substr($$diamond[$r],$c,2)  = "|!";
         substr($$diamond[$r+1],$c,2)= "|!";
    }
   }
   $c = index($$diamond[$r], "AA", $c + 2);
        }
    }
}


my $dimers;

if(rand() < 0.5) {
    $dimers = ["|!", "|!"];
} else {
 $dimers = ["==", "--"];
}

my $n = shift or die "Tell me the order of the diamond please\n";

for(1..$n-1) {
 delete_odd_blocks($dimers);
 $dimers = slide($dimers);
 fill_even_blocks($dimers);
}

for (@$dimers) {
 print "$_\n"
}
```

Here is a sample of the output (the outcome of running "perl shuffle 5" on the command line, if you called this script shuffle):

```
    ==    
   ====   
  |!|!==  
 ||!|!--! 
|||!|!==!!
|||!|!!|!!
 ||--!!|! 
  ||!!--  
   |!--   
    --
```

The domino shuffling algorithm has four types of dominoes: northbound, southbound, eastbound and westbound.  I use "==", "--", for the northbound, southbound ones; two | symbols for the westbound ones and two ! for the eastbound ones.

This script, as I recall, was the first link in a tool chain which produced the following image of the height function of an Aztec Diamond (this link will eventually go stale, but it should be good for a year or two anyway):[image: Order 51 Aztec Diamond]

Comment: lol "shift or *die*" looks like you generate an ascii representation this way.  Can you explain your notation "==", "--", "!|", "|!".

Comment: Edited to include sample output and descriptions of how I represent the dominoes.  The order $n$ tiling is a $2n$-dimensional array of length $2n$ strings, made of the five characters " =-!|".  "==", "--", "!|", "|!" are all portions of the tiling itself.  In particular, "==", "--" are N and S dominoes; "!|" and "|!" are the top half of an odd block and an even block, respectively.  "shift or die" is a perl idiom for reading an argument from the command line and raising an error if it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

There is  http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/tiling/www/applets/  but you should ask Jim Propp.